# Adding libconfig++ to CMake

Tags: cmake, libconfig

I'm trying to add `libconfig++` to my CMake project, but it still complains

```
Libconfig library is config++
...
CMakeFiles/CustomCamReaderTask.dir/acA2440-20gc_ConfigUtility.cc.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN13ConfigSection3getERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERl'
.../lib/libconfig.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(LIBCONFIG_PLUSPLUS libconfig++ REQUIRED)

add_executable(CustomCamReaderTask
    CustomCamReaderTask.cc
    acA2440-20gc_ConfigUtility.cc)

target_include_directories(CustomCamReaderTask
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include/Pylon5
    /opt/pylon5/include)

message("Libconfig library is ${LIBCONFIG_PLUSPLUS_LIBRARIES}")

target_link_libraries(CustomCamReaderTask
    ${LIBCONFIG_PLUSPLUS_LIBRARIES}
    ${PYLON_LIBS}
    task
    imageUtility
    ${OPENCV_LIBRARIES})

link_directories(/opt/pylon5/lib64)
link_libraries(${LIBCONFIG_PLUSPLUS_LIBRARIES})
```

It seems to find config++, I linked the directory, linked the library, not sure what else is wrong..

Comment: Just for being sure, what is output of the `message()` call in your `CMakeLists.txt`? Note, that final `link_directories` and `link_libraries` are not affected on your executable. These commands affect only on targets created **afterwards**.